# Configuring the network of Hyperledger Fabric application

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to configure the network by changing number of orderers and peers by changing the contents of these files-

1. crypto-config.yaml
2. configtx.yaml
3. docker-compose-cli.yaml
4. docker-compose-base.yaml
5. docker-compose.yaml

I want to write these files from scratch . Can you please give me important links which covers each and every detail regarding the contents of these files.

Answer (score 0):

If orderers number is greater than 1, it should be kafka-based.

Here is an example I just done:https://github.com/lissdy/fabric-composer/tree/master/fabric-network/kafka-orderers

It includes 2 orderers, 2 organizations and 2 peers under per organization.